# ILoggingBuilded.AddConsole() works in one project but not the second one in the same solution

Tags: lambda, c#-8.0

I have two projects within the same solution and it looks like the project properties are the same.  I am using .NetCore 3.1.  One of the projects compiles fine.  The second project doesn't.  Both projects have the same code:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder => builder
             .AddConsole()
             .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, level => level == LogLevel.Trace));
```

I have also included "using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" in both .cs files.

The error message I get on the second project is "
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole' and no accessible extension method 'AddConsole' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggingBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I am absolutely stuck and don't understand.

Comment: missing a `using`?

Comment: No I am "using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" already.  Which one are you referring to?

Comment: You need refence to [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/) package.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I do reference Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.

Comment: Update: The code was copied into a Unit Test project, where no console is available. Changed to AddDebug to resolve the issue.